# How to expose button action from some object that call a LWC in MOBILE

Tags: lightning-web-components

> **BUTTON IN RECORD PAGE THAT CALL A QUICK ACTION LWC, DON'T SHOW FOR ME IN MOBILE**

Hello everyone, I need to create a button that opens a quick action and this quick action must be a LWC, I'm trying to use the functionality released by the last release.

I created the button on my object page and placed it inside my layout, the button appears to me perfectly and with the functionality calling my LWC normally,

but my problem is that i need to use it also in the mobile version.

What have I tried to do?

I've tried removing all the buttons and just leaving the button that calls my LWC, but it didn't work.

Important note:

When I create a button that calls a LIGHTNING COMPONENT (aura) the button normally appears to me in the mobile version.

Does anyone know if the functionality is only available for the desktop?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for the details so far, but this site exists to help, not provide full implementation. (Please note in the Help Center section [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that it states, _"Questions that ask for the community to write code or provide step-by-step instructions for implementation...are likely to be closed."_) Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/357371/edit) your question to include what you have tried & how it is not working (e.g., exact errors, issues).

Comment: @Moonpie Sorry Moonpie, I edited the question, sorry about that. It's because, I thinked that the image is enough to understand. Look, i cant want the full implementation, I just want to know if someone pass for the same thing of me... because is to dificult to find this in the net... Look, this site help me a lot, and ever is the last option for me, I just come to make a question when i really dont know what to do.

Comment: I understand, but surely you have tried *something* - maybe adding the button to different layouts, or moving the order of the buttons around. Anything. How did you get the button to appear on your desktop? Just let us know anything that you have done or tried. At the very least maybe no one here will then try to tell you to do something that you have already attempted.

Comment: Hi Moonpie, I'm try to explain in details now, tkssss!

Comment: I've not done much with LWC, so I cannot help directly. Have you tried everything here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions ?

Comment: OMG thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It's not supported...

Comment: Lol - to be honest, I didn't even see that NOTE on that page when I linked to it!

Comment: I thinked you had see and you was being sarcastic with me LOL sorry Moonpie to use your time.

Comment: I am often sarcastic, but I try not to be sarcastic with first time SFSE users who are actually putting effort into solving an issue but who just need help. Like you.  *(Although I should not do it, I have been known to be sarcastic to users who just want someone on SFSE to write all their code or do all their work.)* I'm just glad you found an answer! *Até mais!*

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported.

From https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions on 11 September 2021 *[emphasis added by me]*:

> NOTE Lightning web components are supported only as quick actions in Lightning Experience. **Using a Lightning web component as a quick action isn’t supported in the Salesforce mobile app**.