# Lightning-input with Type="Date" (LWC) displays different size in mobile and desktop

Tags: lightning-web-components

I developed a QuickAction Screen in LWC, that is called from a Aura component thought a custom button and I find a wierd problem.

The width of the **lightning-input** with type="date" is being different when I open the screen from a smartphone.

I'd like to know if someone already pass with a similar problem.

Below you will can see the screenshots:

DESKTOP (WEB)

[image]

SMARTPHONE

[image]

I'm using a aura component to call my LWC:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <c:quickActionPriceBook recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.closeQA}"></c:quickActionPriceBook>
</aura:component>
```

And this is my html lightning-input:

```
<div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-xxl-4 adj-center">
            <div style="font-size: 0.8125rem; float: left;">
                Aprovação
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 col-xxl-8">
           <lightning-input type="date" variant="label-hidden" placeholder="Selecione uma data" dropdown-alignment="left" value={valueUpdateDate} disabled={disabled}> 
           </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap to let my screen responsive, but I already test with **lightning-layout** and i had the same problem.

Comment: are you able to [edit] and share what your html looks like for the lwc?

Comment: And how are you using a LWC quick action in [mobile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357371/how-to-expose-button-action-from-some-object-that-call-a-lwc-in-mobile)? Is it wrapped in an aura component? The more details you can provide, the better chances someone can help or reproduce it.

Comment: Hi guys i edited ,tell me if is more helpfull now.

Comment: For those looking for an answer, the following post might help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386474/my-date-input-field-doesnt-display-icon-and-placeholder-on-mobile

Answer (score 1):

I am using css for that purpose as it was depending on the browser and the device.

The CSS I am using for 'fixing' the look and feel is this:

```
input[type="date"] {
            min-width:95.6%;
            -webkit-appearance : none;
            min-height: calc(var(--lwc-heightInput,1.875rem) + (1px * 2) + 24px) !important;
        }
```

where the important part is the **-webkit-appearance : none**

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi Luisma, do you import in static resource or do you put in the .css lwc folder?

Comment: Static resource, I have not tested in the css of the lwc. To be honest I inject it to the html (manual dom) but for other reasons, but importing css is same result.

Comment: Yes Luisma it work for me, THANKS A LOT!