# My date input field doesn't display icon and placeholder on mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, community, css, html

I'm using a date field in my lwc to use in the community. But it behaves differently between Desktop and Mobile. The placeholder and icon are gone.

Desktop version:

[image]

In mobile:

[image]

How can I keep the data field looking similar to desktop for mobile? Android and IOS.

```
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-form-element" style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning-input type="date" name="input8" variant="label-hidden"  onchange={inputCheckInChange} placeholder="Check-in date" value={dataEntrada} min={minchekin} max={maxcheckin} ></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-form-element" style="padding-right: 0px;">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning-input readonly={checkinInvalido} variant="label-hidden" type="date" name="input8"  onchange={inputCheckOutChange}  placeholder="Check-out date" value={dataSaida} min={mincheckout} max={maxcheckout}></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation), the component renders differently on **mobile** and desktop.
[image]

But that's not the root of the problem.
If I'm not wrong, on desktop `lightning-input` renders date fields as `<input type="text">`. While on **mobile** it renders as `<input type="date">`. That leads us to the root. [HTML documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date)) for `<input type="date">` states that placeholder is not supported for that type:
[image]

I used the following css as a solution for `<lightning:input>`.

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .THIS input[type="date"]:before {
        content: 'yourcontent' !important;
    }

    .THIS input[type="date"]:focus:before {
        content: '' !important;
    }

    .THIS input[type="date"] {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this problem.

```
input[type="date"] {
        min-width:95.6%;
        -webkit-appearance : none;
        min-height: calc(var(--lwc-heightInput,1.875rem) + (1px * 2) + 24px) !important;
    }
```

Source: [Lightning-input with Type="Date" (LWC) displays different size in mobile and desktop](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357421/lightning-input-with-type-date-lwc-displays-different-size-in-mobile-and-des)